# Добавление наследования

Tags: javascript

```
var Class = function(parent){
    var klass = function(){     
        this.name=1002;
    };

    if (parent) {       
       klass.proxy = function(func){
           var self = this ;
           return(function(){
               return func.apply(self, arguments);
           });
        }
        klass.fn.proxy = klass.proxy;
    }

    klass.fn = klass.prototype;
    klass.fn.parent = klass;    
    return klass;
};

var Cat = new Class

// Использование
var tommy = new Cat;

function dd(){
    alert(this.name);
}

tommy.proxy(dd);
```

> TypeError: tommy.proxy is not a function

Будьте добры исправте код или подскажите

Answer (score 3, accepted):

а чего вы ожидали? метод `proxy` создаётся и добавляется в прототип только если указан параметр `parent`, а у вас он не указан, если сделать:

```
var Cat = new Class(true);
```

всё должно работать

Comment: Спасибо.Нужно было еще добавить  
tr=tommy.proxy(dd);
 tr();
и сделать klass.fn = klass.prototype; перед klass.fn.proxy = klass.proxy;

Comment: в чем прикол использования двойного присвоения экземпляра класса к разным переменным?